# Android Google Play Games: Show achievements intent for a specific achievement

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services, google-play-games, achievements

In Google Play Game Services on Android I have created custom achievement previews for the GUI, when tapped they should show the built in achievements intent focused on that specific achievement.

Currently, in the touch event, I am using:

```
Intent intent = Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient());
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentResponseCodes.ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

However this just shows the built in achievements GUI *without the specific achievement focused*.

**Is it possible using *`intent.putExtra(...)`* or some other method to show the same intent, but for a specific achievement?**

Comment: It can't be done using the default UI currently. However, you can retrieve all achievements and their states and build the UI for it yourself.

Comment: @free3dom I feared that was the case. Shame, because I didn't want to deviate too far from the default Google interface users would be familiar with and it seemed like such an obvious feature for them to include.

Comment: They are still changing and improving GPGS, but I wouldn't hold my breath for any advanced features :( I'm assuming it's because they expose everything and hence treat the default view as something of a bare bones template. Pity really, as I would have like some filters in there too.